# What version of python is the one that I cannot uninstall

Tags: big-sur, python

I installed python (newer version than the one shipped with my machine) and it seems to work.
I looked at `pip`, got confused and now I am not sure if I messed up.

- When I execute `python --version` I get `Python 3.9.2`.
- When I do `which python` I get `/usr/local/bin/python`.
- But if I do `which python2` I get `/usr/bin/python2`.
- Lastly if I execute `which python3` I get `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3`.
- When I try to get the pip version with `pip --version` I get `pip 21.1.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)`.

I am not sure if this is correct and I wanted to know the possible issues and solutions. I want to know if I everything is installed correctly as I see python in 3 different directories. If not I want to uninstall them and I want to know which one not to touch.

Comment: How did you install Python? Did you use Homebrew?

Comment: I think I did and that was the issue as I installed it with the installer they provide and then with Homebrew. I deleted all the files I could find and installed it using Homebrew only and that seems to have fixed the issue. But before my installing python command will give me the 2.7 version but python3 command would give me 3.8.... does the system also come with python3 as default?

Comment: You're not alone in this. Not helpful, but at least a little smile: https://xkcd.com/1987/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacOS comes with python2, which is installed in `/usr/bin`.
From Catalina onward, macOS also comes with a 'stub' for python3, which is also in `/usr/bin`.

The first time you run this, it will ask to install the Xcode Command Line Tools, which contain python3, if you don't have Xcode installed already.

`/usr/bin` just contains the 'command': the libraries and meat of the installation is in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`. You can't delete the system pythons without doing all sorts of tricks, so if you can delete it, it's not the system one.

`/usr/bin` is restricted to system software only. Third-party installations will be in `/usr/local`, though I believe homebrew also uses `/opt`.

So anything in `/usr/local` will be a third-party python. The 'meat' of the package is usually installed in `/Library/Frameworks/`.  "If you can delete it, it's not system installed."

Unless you intend to install and use multiple pythons at the same time, I find using the python installer directly from https://www.python.org/downloads/ to be much easier than Homebrew, which seems to complicate matters. *(Others may disagree.)*

Answer (score 0):

MacOS comes with preinstalled versions of Python (which depend upon the version of MacOS you have). It is important not to change or remove these as there are going to be other application or system dependencies on them.

I used the Homebrew installation to install Python 3.9.5. This install is missing a couple of steps (likely by design) which you will need to do afterwards. Try the following:

1. Edit your shell e.g. .zshrc to update the PATH to find the correct versions of Python and it's dependencies e.g. add "export PATH=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:/Users/java/Library/Python/3.9/bin:$PATH"
2. Install the tk dependency so you can run IDLE from the command line e.g.
   type "brew install python-tk"

Results from a current installation of Homebrew followed by steps 1 & 2 above should be similar to below:

```
java@Tests-iMac ~ % which python
/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python
java@Tests-iMac ~ % python --version
Python 3.9.5
java@Tests-iMac ~ % which pip
/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/pip
java@Tests-iMac ~ % pip --version
pip 21.1.2 from /Users/java/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
java@Tests-iMac ~ %
```